# Optical zoom in webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net

I successfully use webbrowser control from VB.NET to show and print documents but I can't get zoom functionality which I would like to apply.

For example you can create a new project, add a form with "Webbrowser1" control and two buttons "btn_Plus" and "btn_Minus".
Don't forget to add COM reference to "Microsoft Internet Controls".

```
Option Strict Off 'because of late binding MyWeb.ExecWB
Imports SHDocVw

Public Class Form1
Dim zoomvalue As Integer = 50

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim strHtml As String = "<HTML><h1>Doc...<h1></br><h4>My html here</br>acts like web page.<h4></HTML>"
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:" + strHtml)
End Sub

Private Sub zoom()
    Try
        Dim MyWeb As Object = Me.WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
        MyWeb = Me.WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
        MyWeb.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, zoomvalue, IntPtr.Zero)
        MyWeb = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show("Error:" & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Plus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Plus.Click
    zoomvalue += 5
    zoom()
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Minus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Minus.Click
    zoomvalue -= 5
    zoom()
End Sub
End Class
```

1) Why this won't work and I think it should work?
2) How to get this to work?
3) How to get current zoom value from actual webbrowser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try MyWeb.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, **CObj**(zoomvalue), **CObj**(IntPtr.Zero))